# Como usar cv2.imread() com um objeto do tipo imagem ao invés de "image path"?

Tags: python, opencv

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
import cv2, pyautogui

screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
cv2.imread(screenshot, 0)
```

Ao invés disso:

```
import cv2, pyautogui
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot("imagem.png")
cv2.imread("imagem.png", 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu não entendi direito o propósito, mas se você quer simplesmente salvar a imagem para usá-la novamente com o OpenCV, você pode utilizar o método [`save()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-image-save-method/) da imagem dessa forma:

```
pil_image = pyautogui.screenshot()
pil_image.save("<Nome_do_arquivo>")

image = cv2.imread("<Nome_do_arquivo>")
```

Caso o que você queira seja na verdade converter a imagem diretamente sem salvar para usar com o OpenCV, o processo será um pouquinho mais complicado e você irá precisar utilizar a biblioteca `numpy` para isso.

Primeiro, você deve transformar sua imagem em um objeto de `numpy.array` e depois disso você deve convertê-la de RGB para BGR. Veja abaixo:

```
pil_image = pyautogui.screenshot()
image = numpy.array(pil_image)

# Converte de RGB para BGR
image = image[:, :, ::-1].copy()

cv2.imshow("Imagem", image)
```

Comment: Um atalho para .save seria simplesmente: `pyautogui.screenshot('<Nome_do_arquivo>')` ;)

Comment: Era exatamente o segundo exemplo que eu precisava. Porém eu também gostaria de usar a função do cv2.imshow de transformar a imagem em grayscale (cv2.imshow(img, 0). Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso com o numpy.array ?

Comment: @x8ss image já é a imagem no padrão do OpenCV, no espaço de cores BGR. Basta converter `image` para o espaço de cores em escala de cinza com a função `cv2.cvtColor` do OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

na verdade você não precisa fazer nada.

faz este teste:

```
import cv2, pyautogui

screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
####### editado
img_opencv = cv2.imencode('.jpg', screenshot )[1].tostring()
####### editado
cv2.imshow("teste",img_opencv )
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

ele vai abrir uma janela com o print que você tirou.

Comment: Eu precisava do imread() para conseguir aplicar algoritmos de reconhecimento de imagem

Comment: ai q ta quando vc usa o pyautogui ele ja gera um jpg de uma forma que o opencv entende mas caso vc realmente precise forcar um estado da imagem faz igual eu editei la em cima

Comment: dai dependendo do q vc vai fazer he so convertar para gray ou modificar o tamanho para rede neural q vc for usar.